# Cannot Find Who sold most or less in sql. It returns only first row in group

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code snippet. I tried to find who sold most and less but it returned only the first row in group.

```
    SELECT 
        branches.branch_name as Branch, 
        cities.city_name as Province, 
        districts.district_name as District, 
        salesmans.salesman_name as EmpNameMost, 
        salesmans.salesman_surname as EmpSurMost, 
        MAX(salesmans.sale_count) as SaleAmtMost,
        salesmans.salesman_name as EmpNameLeast, 
        salesmans.salesman_surname as EmpSurLeast, 
        MIN(salesmans.sale_count) as SaleAmtLeast 
    FROM salesmans JOIN branches 
        ON salesmans.branch_id = branches.branch_id 
    JOIN cities 
        ON branches.city_id = cities.city_id 
    JOIN districts 
        ON cities.district_id = districts.district_id 
    WHERE districts.district_name = 'Marmara Bölgesi' 
    GROUP BY branches.branch_name;
```

Output of my code:

[image: Output of my code]

Comment: Your query is malformed and should be generating an error.  The `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY`.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O.  It appears you may have an incorrect understanding of the min/max functions in the query.  These and also count(), sum(), avg(), etc. are considered aggregate functions.  The "Group By" says to get the minimum or maximum for a given group. In this case, you are grouping by just the branch name, so it is going over all sales people and pulling the minimum and maximum counts and sticking it on a single row for the branch.

What you need is going to be a nested-query.  You need to first find the minimum and maximum per the branch, THEN find the sales people who had those values.

```
select
        MinMaxPerBranch Province, 
        MinMaxPerBranch District, 
        s.salesman_name EmpNameMost, 
        s.salesman_surname EmpSurMost, 
        s.salesman_name EmpNameLeast, 
        s.salesman_surname EmpSurLeast, 
        s.sale_count SaleAmtMost,
        s.sale_count SaleAmtLeast,
        case when s.sale_count = MinMaxPerBranch.SaleAmtMost
             then 'Highest Sales' else 'Lowest Sales' end SalesResult
    FROM
       ( select
                s2.branch_id,
                -- to get district and city while we have the joins, pull the
                -- max() on those too since they wont change per their respective
                -- branch. Prevents needing to re-join again on next part of query
                max( d2.district_name ) as District,
                max( c2.city_name ) Province,
                MAX(s2.sale_count) SaleAmtMost,
                MIN(s2.sale_count) SaleAmtLeast 
            FROM
                salesmans s2
                    JOIN branches b2
                        ON s2.branch_id = b2.branch_id 
                        JOIN cities c2
                            ON b2.city_id = c2.city_id
                            JOIN districts d2
                                ON c2.district_id = d2.district_id 
                                AND d2.district_name = 'Marmara Bölgesi' 
            group by
                -- branch_id is the smallest granularity within city and district
                s2.branch_id ) MinMaxPerBranch

        JOIN salesmans s
            -- THIS part will join back to the sales people, but ONLY if they 
            -- have the matching lowest or highest for the branch.
            on MinMaxPerBranch.Branch_id = s.branch_id
            AND (  MinMaxPerBranch.SaleAmtMost = s.sale_count
                OR MinMaxPerBranch.SaleAmtLeast = s.sale_count )
```